# Create static librarys including different components

Tags: ios, xcode

In my static library including some different components, and now I want to package some libraries including several components to meet the requirement of different developers.

for example I have four **.m** files

> a.m b.m c.m d.m

for four modules.

Now I only want to create one target with all compile sources, then create some shell targets to package all kinds of libraries, for example if there is a target called CreateLibraryWithA&BComponent, I only want to compile a.m and b.m in the compile sources of build phases. Now I know I can use xcodebuild command with GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="a=1 b=1 " to create create a library with a and b components, but I don't know how to control including or excluding the compile files.

Comment: Define what you mean by "module".  Also you cannot easily do this from Xcode with a single target.  What's wrong with including *all*  implementation files?

Comment: I don't want to include all m files because the library file will become larger with something that the developer don't need.

Comment: And why is that a problem?  Hard disk is cheap and internet bandwidth is large.  The linker will only include the object files it needs, so I fail to see the issue.

Comment: I don't think so, the problem is not how cheap the hard disk is or how large the bandwidth is, I think that's a method to solve one kind of problem, may be one component size is  hundreds mbs, or maybe you are in a environment with low bandwidth, I just want to find a method to solve one kind of problem. and maybe the method can use in other problems, nobody knows.